# register date verification

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to delete users that didn't verify their account in 5 minutes.

I have a db that automaticly adds a registration date in this format:`current_timestamp(6)` and for example: `2020-05-12 17:38:33.308392` .

I have a php script that tries to check if a user isn't validated and 5 minutes haven't passed:

```
$sql ="DELETE FROM users WHERE createdate < ? AND verified = ?;";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("Location:../register.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();                            
    }
    else{  
        $a = 1;
        $date = date("U") + 300;
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $date, $a);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
```

I'm assuming that the code doesn't work because the date("U") function doesn't produce the same date format/type.

how should I solve this problem? enter the date("U") function to the database or is there a way to make sql recognize the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MySQL interval](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval/) in combination with TIMESTAMPADD and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to add 5 minutes to it.

```
    DELETE FROM users WHERE 
  (TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,5,createdate)) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
 AND verified = ?;
```

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
    Select * from `time`;

| id  | date                       |
| --- | -------------------------- |
| 1   | 2020-05-19 17:38:33.308392 |
| 2   | 2020-05-13 11:57:35.567192 |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jPQxCvQrDBdvj3WEGaUYdL/1)